# why is my jquery selecting all text values

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I want to be able to fetch a number from a table cell and multiply it by an input on focusout, however the selector is grabbing all the table cells with the name front in the front. here is the code:

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".percent").focusout(function(){
        var val2 = $(this).val();
        if (val2==="") {
            val2=0;
        }
        var crew2 = $(this).attr("name"),
            front = $(".front, td[name='front"+crew2+"']").text();
        console.log(crew2);
        console.log(front);
    });
});
```

html:

```
<tr>
    <td class='front' name='frontI210'>$176.00</td>
    <td><input type='text' class='percent' name='I210' style='' size='4' /></td>
    <td>=</td>
    <td class='total' id='I210'></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class='front' name='frontI250'>$225.00</td>
    <td><input type='text' class='percent' name='I250' style='' size='4' /></td>
    <td>=</td>
    <td class='total' id='I250'></td>
</tr>
```

and console.log(front) is returning all the text of fronti210 and fronti250 as such:

```
$176.00$225.00
```

I want to only receive the information from the table cell that matches the input field name i just finished with, how do i do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`$(".front, td[name='front"+crew2+"']")` searchers for all elements with class `front` as well as all `td` elements with the `name` `frontXXX`. The comma is the [*multiple selector* <sup>[docs]</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/).

Either only search for `td` elements with that name:

```
var front = $("td[name='front"+crew2+"']").text();
```

or use DOM traversal:

```
var front = $(this).closest('tr').children('.front').text();
```

Comment: Nice, didn't know about .closest().

Answer (score 4):

```
$(".front, td[name='front"+crew2+"']").text();
//this___^ is the culprit.
```

The comma is basically saying I want all elements with the class `front` and all td elements with the specified name.

What you want is probably:

```
$("td[name='front"+crew2+"'].front").text();
```

Thought I haven't tested that, and the syntax may be off slightly.